# Storing data in booking system in python

Tags: python-3.x, schedule

I have a project that asks the user for the preferred time and date that he/she wants to rent a studio. I want to save the data of the user's input to avoid repeating the schedule for the next user to input in the program. I still haven't added the loop function to my program. The schedule worked but I needed to add a function that stores the schedule inputted by the user.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXt45.png)

while True:
booking_str = input("Enter preferred date and time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM): ")
try:
# parse the input date and time string
user_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(booking_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

```
    # print the parsed date and time
    print(f"Booked at {user_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M')}")

    # Exit the loop
    break

except ValueError:
    print("Invalid date format. Please use YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but from what I understand, if you want to save the state of the schedule to use after the program is restarted, you can use a file to store the schedule data and read it when the program starts. This can be done with a JSON file, you can store and fetch data from it.

Here's the modified code with an explanation:

```py
import datetime
import json

# Initialize the schedule dictionary
schedule = {}

# Try to load the schedule data from a JSON file
try:
    with open("schedule.json", "r") as file:
        schedule = json.load(file)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("No existing schedule data found. Starting with an empty schedule.")

while True:
    booking_str = input("Enter preferred date and time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM): ")
    try:
        user_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(booking_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        date_key = user_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        time_value = user_date.strftime('%H:%M')

        if date_key in schedule:
            if time_value in schedule[date_key]:
                print(f"Time {time_value} on {date_key} is already booked.")
            else:
                schedule[date_key].append(time_value)
                print(f"Booked at {user_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}")
        else:
            schedule[date_key] = [time_value]
            print(f"Booked at {user_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}")

    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid date format. Please use YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format")

    # Optionally, you can print the entire schedule
    print("Current Schedule:")
    for date, times in schedule.items():
        print(f"{date}: {', '.join(times)}")

    # Ask the user if they want to continue booking
    response = input("Do you want to book another time? (yes/no): ")
    if response.lower() != "yes":
        # Save the schedule to the JSON file before exiting
        with open("schedule.json", "w") as file:
            json.dump(schedule, file)
        break
```

With this code, the schedule is loaded from the "schedule.json" file at the beginning, and any changes to the schedule are saved back to the file when the user chooses to exit. This way, the schedule data will be retained even if the program is restarted.

Lastly, in the future, please format and word your question in a better way to allow users to understand what exactly you are trying to do. Also, please make proper use of code blocks for your code.